# How to get a tag from a branch in my repository using github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, workflow, git-tag

I need to automatically capture the latest tag whenever I push changes to my private repository on the 'develop' branch and store it in a variable. How can I achieve this?

I attempted to use these commands to retrieve the tag, but I did not succeed using this approach.

```
name: get-tag-version

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  get-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: "0"
      - name: catch tag
        run: tags=$(git describe --tags --all)
      - name: show tag
        run: echo "$tag"
```

the cli returns this:

```
`Run echo "$tag"
  echo "$tag"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}`
```

---

**[SOLVED]**

I managed to get the tag using these commands.

```
 describe-tags:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Describe Tags
        run: |
          git fetch --prune --unshallow
          latest_tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD~)
          echo "Latest Tag: $latest_tag"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe variables are not shared between subsequent run steps, you'd have to you step outputs for that.

You can run multiple commands in one step:

```yaml
run: |
     tags=$(git describe --tags --all)
     echo "$tags"
```

For stuff like this I highly recommend getting your desired behavior to work locally for quicker testing and easier debugging.

Comment: `echo "$tag"` >> `echo "$tags"`